# Please verify this proof in sequences.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ and let $(a_j)$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{Q}$ converging to $\alpha$. Assume $a_j$ is a fraction in lowest terms: $a_j = \alpha_j / \beta_j$. Show $\beta_j$ goes to infinity.

This is my proof What have I missed here?..

For all $\epsilon >0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that 
    $\forall n \ge N$,  $|\frac{\alpha_n}{\beta_n}-\alpha|<\epsilon$.

We want to show for all $M>0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \ge N$, $ \beta_n \ge M$.

Claim that there exists $\gamma >0$ such that $|\alpha_n-\alpha \beta_n| \ge \gamma$. Then set $|\frac{\alpha_n}{\beta_n}-\alpha| < \frac{\gamma}{|\beta_n|}$ $|\frac{\alpha_n-\alpha \beta_n}{\beta_n}| \ge \frac{\gamma}{|\beta_n|}$ $ |\beta_n| \ge |\frac{\gamma}{\alpha_n-\alpha \beta_n}| \ge M$ Thus $\beta_j$ tend to $\infty$. $\square$

Answer (score 0):

The error is in setting $|\frac{\alpha_n}{\beta_n}-\alpha|<\frac{\gamma}{|\beta_n|}$ which is essentially a contradiction to the assumption that $|\alpha_n-\alpha\beta_n|\ge \gamma$. Instead set, for any $M>0$, some $N>0$ such that $\forall n\ge N, |\frac{\alpha_n}{\beta_n}-\alpha|<\frac{\gamma}{M}$ which will lead to $|\beta_n|>M\forall n>N$

Comment: Oh I think it works

Comment: How can I prove by subsequences tho? @Samrat

Comment: I don't see any subsequence in my answer. Which subsequence are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

You don't explain why you think you've missed something, you get to the point you're trying to proove.

However setting  to be less than $|\gamma/\beta_n$ is nothing that could obviously done, if you're thinking you can select a $n$ such that this is true then it's not the same $n$ as in the previos claim $|\alpha_n-\alpha\beta_n|\ge\gamma$. As you pointed out the $\gamma$ is chosen for a given $n$, but the $|\alpha_m/\beta_m-\alpha|<\gamma$ is true for all $m>\omega$, where $\omega$ depends on $\gamma$ which in turn depends on $n$. It's not obvious that $\omega < n$.

The simple solution to this problem is to observe that if $\beta_j$ does not go to infinity there's a subsequence where $\beta_j$ is limited. As the sequence is convergent then so is it's subsequence, but since $\beta_j$ is limited we can choose a common denominator $b\in\mathbb Z$. Now we have a sequence $a_j = \alpha_j/b$ that is convergent so $\alpha_j$ is convergent sequence of integers which limit must be an integer, that is $a$ is rational.

To see that a sequence $\beta j$ that does not go to infinity has a limited sub sequence you just have to negate the definition for going to infinity. That is there is a $K$ such that for every $N$ there exists an $j>N$ such that $\beta_j \le K$. Given that $K$ we can generate an infinite number of $\beta_j \le K$ by observing that for a given $j$ there exists an $k>j$ such that $\beta_k \le K$.

Comment: The former claim regarding the existence of some $\gamma>0$ such that $|\alpha_n-\alpha\beta_n|\ge \gamma$ is true since otherwise we would have $\alpha_n=\alpha\beta_n$ which is a contradiction since $\alpha$ is irrational.

Comment: I approached using subsequences. So I suppose there exists a subsequence $\beta_{n_k}$ s.t. $\beta_{n_k} \le M$ for all k. So I got

Comment: $-M(1+\alpha)<(1-\alpha)\beta_{n_k}<a_{n_k}<(1+\alpha)\beta_{n_k}<M(1+\alpha)$

Comment: You pressed enter early? If $\beta_j\le M$ then all $\beta_j$ will be a factor of $\beta=M!$ so $\alpha_j/\beta_j = \alpha_j(M!/\beta_j)/M!$

Comment: No I suppose βnk is not goes to infinity

Comment: $\alpha_j(M!/\beta j)$ are integers so $\lim \alpha_j/\beta_j = M!^{-1} \lim \alpha_j(M!/\beta_j)$ is a rational number since the limit of a integer sequence is an integer.

Comment: Hey, could you explain your last paragraph again? So you are proving there is subsequences if $\beta_j$ does not go to infinity?

Comment: @user275310 What do you think is unclear? That if not $\beta_j\to\infty$ then theres a bounded subsequence?

Comment: I just figured it out. Thanks a lot